# Create Standalone Angular Project in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

My company predominantly use Visual Studio (currently 2017) for all development due to its easy integration with Azure DevOps for source control etc.

I have been asked to start looking into building enterprise apps with Angular using a .NET Core Web API backend.

I have already made a start with the Web API and now I want to build the Angular frontend.

Q. How can I create a separate Angular project in Visual Studio. I don't want my Angular code sitting in the same Web API project (how the Visual Studio Template tries to do it)

I have built Angular apps in VS Code before, but I have yet found a convenient extension to allow me to push code changes to Azure DevOps repo.

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably quite a few ways to do this, but here is the way I do it:

```
project
  backend
     backend.sln
     backend (folder with your vanilla Web API project)
  frontend
     angular.json
     package.json
     src (folder with your Angular CLI project)
```

So from a creation perspective, you'd just do something like (using Windows)

`mkdir project`

`cd project`

`dotnet new webapi backend -o backend`

`ng new frontend`

The last bit is configuring your Angular app to point to your local web api for development. We accomplish this with a config.json file that gets loaded from a `ConfigService` in Angular, [doing something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925134/get-data-from-config-json-in-angular-2). Our `config.json` looks something like this:

```
{
  "environment": "DEV",
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:17967/",
}
```

You'd change that, obviously, for production. Not sure that's what you're looking for, but maybe gives you some ideas?